# Как использовать данные из запроса в том же запросе в SQl

Tags: postgresql

Есть цены с НДС (НДС разный 10% и 20%), есть список продуктов с НДС=10%, остальные 20%. Нужно выделить НДС в отдельный столбец `tax`. А затем создать еще столбец с ценой без НДС `price_before_tax`.
Как теперь применить новые данные из `tax` в одном запросе?

```sql
SELECT product_id, name, price, 
CASE WHEN name IN ('сахар', 'сухарики', 'сушки', 'семечки', 
'масло льняное', 'виноград', 'масло оливковое', 
'арбуз', 'батон', 'йогурт', 'сливки', 'гречка', 
'овсянка', 'макароны', 'баранина', 'апельсины', 
'бублики', 'хлеб', 'горох', 'сметана', 'рыба копченая', 
'мука', 'шпроты', 'сосиски', 'свинина', 'рис', 
'масло кунжутное', 'сгущенка', 'ананас', 'говядина', 
'соль', 'рыба вяленая', 'масло подсолнечное', 'яблоки', 
'груши', 'лепешка', 'молоко', 'курица', 'лаваш', 'вафли', 'мандарины')
THEN round(price/110*10, 2)
ELSE round(price/120*20, 2) end as tax
FROM products
```

Как теперь создать столбец `price_before_tax`?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
SELECT *, new_table.price - new_table.tax AS price_before_tax
  FROM (SELECT product_id, name, price, 
CASE WHEN name IN ('сахар', 'сухарики', 'сушки', 'семечки', 
'масло льняное', 'виноград', 'масло оливковое', 
'арбуз', 'батон', 'йогурт', 'сливки', 'гречка', 
'овсянка', 'макароны', 'баранина', 'апельсины', 
'бублики', 'хлеб', 'горох', 'сметана', 'рыба копченая', 
'мука', 'шпроты', 'сосиски', 'свинина', 'рис', 
'масло кунжутное', 'сгущенка', 'ананас', 'говядина', 
'соль', 'рыба вяленая', 'масло подсолнечное', 'яблоки', 
'груши', 'лепешка', 'молоко', 'курица', 'лаваш', 'вафли', 'мандарины')
THEN round(price/110*10, 2)
ELSE round(price/120*20, 2) end as tax
FROM products) new_table
```

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую позже) Уже нашел другое решение, добавил еще CASE WHEN, только round(price - price/110*10,2) as price_before_tax